# is it possible to set multiple state variables in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is given simple react chat container, which successully grabs data with `LoadConversationInformation` function as following

```
var ConversationContainer = React.createClass({
    LoadConversationInformation: function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.props.getMessageUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
               this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    ...
    render: function () {
        var Chat = this.state.data.map(function (message) {
            return (
                <MessageContainer message={message} key={message.id}/>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {Chat}
                <MessageForm onMessageSubmit={this.handleMessageSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

It is required to check if in first element of `data` exists some attribute, if so, add it to separate state variable, like this:

```
     ...
        success: function (data) {
            if ('hasContactRequest' in data[0]) {
                this.setState({
                    data: data,
                    hasContactRequest: data[0].hasContactRequest
                });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }
        }.bind(this),
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    ...
```

To make possible in `ConversationContainer` child check for it and render some element, if it is present, like this:

```
    var MessageContainer = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <li className={(this.props.message.type === 'sender') ? 'sender' : 'receiver'}>
                    <MessageImage />
                    <MessageDate date={this.props.message.date}/>
                    <MessageText text={this.props.message.text}/>
                    {(this.state.hasContactRequest ? <MessageSendContacts/> : null)}
                </li>
            );
        }
    });
```

Generally chat is working but i cant get no luck of adding this additional state variable, and access it like `this.state.hasContactRequest`
got:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasContactRequest' of null`

How to properly do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessageContainer has no state, that's the reason why you are getting that error.

You should pass hasContactRequest as a prop to your MessageContainer

```
var Chat = this.state.data.map(function (message) {
            return (
                <MessageContainer hasContactRequest={this.state.hasContactRequest} message={message} key={message.id}/>
            );
        });
```

and use it

```
 var MessageContainer = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <li className={(this.props.message.type === 'sender') ? 'sender' : 'receiver'}>
                    <MessageImage />
                    <MessageDate date={this.props.message.date}/>
                    <MessageText text={this.props.message.text}/>
                    {(this.props.hasContactRequest ? <MessageSendContacts/> : null)}
                </li>
            );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var MessageContainer = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <li className={(this.props.message.type === 'sender') ? 'sender' : 'receiver'}>
                    <MessageImage />
                    <MessageDate date={this.props.message.date}/>
                    <MessageText text={this.props.message.text}/>
                    {(this.state.hasContactRequest ? <MessageSendContacts/> : null)}
                </li>
            );
        }
    });
```

Maybe you need to use props here, not state?

```
{(this.state.hasContactRequest ? <MessageSendContacts/> : null)}
```

Answer (score 1):

cause the state of MessageContainer got nothing. the state you used in MessageContainer is the state of ConversationContainer. Although MessageContainer is child of ConversationContainer, it cannot get the state of it's parent Component ie ConversationContainer. you should pass hasContactRequest to MessageContainer as prop like this:

```
render: function () {
  var Chat = this.state.data.map(function (message) {
      return (
          <MessageContainer message={message} hasContactRequest={this.state.hasContactRequest} key={message.id}/>
      );
  });
  return (
      <div>
          {Chat}
          <MessageForm onMessageSubmit={this.handleMessageSubmit}/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

then in MessageContainer:

```
return (
<li className={(this.props.message.type === 'sender') ? 'sender' : 'receiver'}>
    <MessageImage />
    <MessageDate date={this.props.message.date}/>
    <MessageText text={this.props.message.text}/>
    {(this.props.hasContactRequest ? <MessageSendContacts/> : null)}
</li>
```

);